# Check Update for software and update software without effecting database

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

We are install a desktop application at several client places. Now, We have found some bugs in software, So is there any way to update that software online?
Problem is we cannot install new setup as it is hectic and also will cost us high.
Clients do not want to re-enter all data in software again. We have a database backup option, but what about the tables which we modified? What can be done in this case?

Technology : Dot Net (WPF) & SQL Server 2008 R2

I have created setup using setup wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can (at least my company does) like this: you put updating sql queries and execute them at the beginning of the program being opened if the version of the program is higher than the version record in the database.

Comment: Thanks 
But how can update software from online.